# how to create a custom client portal

Tags: visualforce, customer-portal

> I am doing a project where the client wants to use the salesforce
>   platform to create an area where the customer can perform and track
>   their sales orders, and they can also lodge complaints.

- It is possible to do this with the SalesForce? I thought about using
  the customer portal, however the same can not be implemented in
  accordance with the requirements.
- It is possible to build it using Visualforce? And how would be the
  authentication process Working? Licensing?

Any material, are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Getting Started with Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/) for more about the solution you're looking for.